# Is there any comparation operator applied for matrixs in Matlab, like the dot operator '.*', './', '.^'

Tags: matlab, matrix, dot-operator

I have function f like this

```
function z=f(x,y)
    if(x<1 & y <1)
        z=0;
    else
        z=1;
    end
 end
```

And a script

```
x=0:0.1:2;
y=0:0.1:2;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=f(X,Y);
mesh(X,Y,Z);
```

When running this script, I got this errors:
Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

It's because x and y here are two arrays, not scalar value. The script can run if I change the

```
function f looks like this:
     function z = f( x,y )
     for i=1:size(x,2)
         for j=1:size(y,2)
             if(x(i)<1 & y(j)<1)
                 z(i,j)=0;
             else
                 z(i,j)=1;
             end
         end
     end
     end
```

The broblem is that the new function runs much slower than the first one. I don't know if there is any comparation operator applied for arrays in this case, like the ".*" operator used in this function

```
function z=f(x,y)
    z=x.*y;
 end
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error, because the function `f(x,y)` returns a scalar for `z` and `mesh` expects `z` to be a matrix. You can replace all of the functions and code above with a simple, fast vectorized solution, that uses [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
x=0:0.1:2;
y=0:0.1:2;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=ones(size(X));
Z(X(:)<1&Y(:)<1)=0;

mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

This produces the following figure

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. The idea using logical indexing is great. My problems are solved.

Comment: @James: Glad to have helped. Perhaps you're not aware of it, but you can mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to the answer, so that it makes it easier for others who might have the same problem to find the solution that worked.

Answer (score 0):

to quote Mr Mackey: for loops with indexed matrices are bad, mkay? It takes up a lot of time, mkay?

I will modify Yoda's code a notch for the sake of efficiency:

```
x=0:0.1:2;
y=0:0.1:2;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z = ((X>1) | (Y>1))*1;
mesh(X,Y,Z);
```